# Which cookware is best from health perspective?

Tags: food-safety, lasting-effects-duration, benefits, metal, healthy-cooking

Cookwares are made up of various materials. Which cookware is best from health perspective? Please include anodised aluminium and stainless steel in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The best cookware is made up of clay. It is very healthy and good for you body. 
Clay pots prove good for slow cooking as their porous nature allows both moisture and heat to circulate easily through them. ...
Clay being alkaline in nature helps in neutralising the pH balance of the food by interacting with the acid present in the food.

Wood is also very beneficial for your health.. while Plastic is really dangerous from all perspectives.

Comment: You can’t claim that wood‘s good for your health - ever tried chewing it. The alkaline part only makes sense as long as your food is acidic (which it isn’t necessarily), once you start eating pretzels and alike (which are already alkaline), it‘s the negative effect you wanted to avoid. Please explain how clay is good for your body? Should we all start to consume pallets of clay and wood?

Answer (score -4):

The only safe alternative I've seen is ceramic (not glazed with lead/nickel/aluminium etc)

You should avoid especially aluminium and stainless as it can leach and cause bad health effects(aluminium leaches alot more). Avoid the non stick scam,they are coated with plenty of plastic/polymers causing various lymphatic illness.
There is ceramic that is safe, and maybe graphite cookware .

Source with 12 studies linked :https://donate.ewg.org/images/ewg_teflontempinfo_c02.pdf

In the meantime you can cook your food at less high temperature(avoid higher than 240 celcius,which makes it almost useless) ,or cook in glass/borosilicate or ceramic in the oven,until you get a pan. Using oil to cook and not leaving it unattained will reduce alot of non-stick,and you can wash it straight after also.There is natural stick resistant ceramic enough for any if not most foods needs.

Also don't trust any compagny using fluoride/chloride(or polymers/plastics) in cookware,I will not enter into the who would want people to ingest that,but the same thing is in water,in some transformed food ,which blocks the thyroid,pineal and alot of glands if not all of them. Notice how overcommercialised it is and almost everyone has one ? Also the Fda is so biased and hiding cures that I don't trust anything from them.

According to Environmental Working Group :
" Exposure to PFCs has been associated with kidney and testicular cancer,
high cholesterol, abnormal thyroid hormone levels, pregnancy-induced
hypertension and preeclampsia, obesity and low birth weight – all good
reasons to reduce your exposure. "

I don't really have the time to find all the studies, altought I have checked on Ncbi/Pubmed ,on that website aluminium is very proven to leach(example aluminium cookware in oven and cofee percolator, stainless also but to a much lower extend(stainless is very often alloyed with nickel,chromium,molydbenum, it is still a health risk on the long term. Just another way of getting cancer or another illness.

I also don't have the concrete proof but I've seen people claiming fluoride increased aluminium effect/transportation in the brain.

Comment: Do you have any reputable scientific references for this claim? It is my understanding that, when used properly (i.e. not overheated or scratched) PTFE (aka, Teflon if you're DuPont) coated cookware is perfectly safe. Here is [one:] (http://swac.web.unc.edu/thepipettepen/ask-a-toxicologist-is-it-safe-to-use-teflon-pans/)

Comment: I found one study that links 12 studies https://donate.ewg.org/images/ewg_teflontempinfo_c02.pdf
At 680° F (360 degres celcius) Easily attainable on stove...!
Toxic gasses released:
TFE (tetrafluoroethylene)
animal carcinogen
HFP (hexafluoropropene)
worker toxicant
TFA (trifluoroacetic acid)
poisonous to plants
DFA (difluoroacetic acid)
Animal kidney toxicant
MFA (monofluoroacetic acid)
lethal to humans at low doses
PFOA (perfluorooctanoic acid)
animal carcinogen

Comment: While 680° might be easily attainable on a stove, it is almost never encountered during normal cooking. And we're talking about normal PTFE, not the byproducts it produces when overheated.

Comment: Alot of people cook on the highest setting so yes it is encountered in normal cooking. This is a concern also for stainless,iron or aluminium recipients.
Theres not only PTFE, and we're talking about cookware in general.

Comment: Palm oil has a smoke point of 455°F and auto-ignites a few degrees above that, so I hope anyone cooking on a pot heated to 680°F isn't using anything but 30w crankcase oil.

Comment: Please include resources in your answer.